# Using getItemId() always get 0 in onActionItemClicked

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionmode

I'm using `com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode` and when I try to get the clicked `item id` like this:

```
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(WeiboActivity.this, "Got click: " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

it's always:

> Got click: 0

So what is the right code to get the clicked item id?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include item id in your call when you created the menu item

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_test, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_test)
```